# I can't find to adjust the height of the media queries

Tags: css, media-queries

I am targeting the 320x480 and 320x568. The issue i am facing in 320x568 Portrait view. Everything is working fine on 320x480 but in 320x568 portrait view, the size of the container is very large. I tried everything to adjust the height but it is not showing the same as 320*480 portrait view. I can't find the way to solve this issue. You can check the screenshot below:

You can check the site here through your mobile - bit.ly/1bD6EhX

[image]

I have to move the text to top position but when i do this, this will also affect the 320*480 portrait view. Here is my code below:

```
.container3 {
        margin:0;
        height:750px;
        overflow:hidden; 
    }

    .fullwidth3 {
        width:100%;   
    }

    .mobtxt {
        margin:0 0 0 25px;
        font-size:22px;
        font-weight:600;
        font-family:'Open Sans', arial, helvetica;
        letter-spacing:0;
        text-align:center;
        width:80%;
        border-bottom:2px solid #e0e0e0;
    }

    .mobdes {
       margin:15px 0 0 10px;
        font-size:16px;
        font-weight:normal;
        font-family:arial;
        letter-spacing:0;
        text-align:left;
        width:95%;

    }


    .mobdes2 {
        position:absolute;
        top:320%;
        width:95%;
        margin:15px 0 0 10px;
        font-size:arial;
        font-size:15px;
        color:#adadad;
        padding:0;

    }

    .mobimg {
        width:100%;
        clear:both;
        float:none;
        margin-left:0;
        margin-right:0;
        right:10px;
        margin-top:30px;

    }


HTML File

<div class="container3">
        <div class="fullwidth3">    
            <p class="mobtxt">We have an experience of 10 Years</p>
            <p class="mobdes">Mandaremus veniam dolor ita sunt, duis praesentibus vidisse velit ingeniis qui 
                sed est dolore fore eram a do aute incurreret transferrem ab se qui culpa 
                eiusmod, quem iis pariatur, an culpa magna legam occaecat o in qui quorum legam 
                quem. Singulis exquisitaque ut quamquam, ita ea tractavissent, nam sint de quis 
                est quo a tractavissent. </p>

            <img src="img/mobimg.png" alt="mob image" class="mobimg" >
          <hr class="hr"/>

           <p class="mobdes2">Laborum duis malis in duis, duis ingeniis nam transferrem, nam quis commodo, de 
                nisi varias illum nescius si probant ipsum in laborum exercitation, ut a 
                comprehenderit, iis aliqua praesentibus, e nisi litteris expetendis.</p>

        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont understand, why you are doing `top:320%;` in `.mobdes2`. I think you want to do it `top:320px`. However, it would be better if you'd have provided the HTML as well.

But, I would recomend you to use `vh` unit of css 3. This just mean the viewport height as unit.

**Example:** http://snook.ca/archives/html_and_css/vm-vh-units

**Browser support:** http://caniuse.com/#feat=viewport-units

Good luck!!

Comment: May I please know - why you are doing things in position:absolute? I mean whats wrong in it: http://jsfiddle.net/ashishanexpert/R8h5k/1/

Comment: I have added absolute to see whether the position can change according to the height. I have added the screenshot. Can you check this 320x568 is showing correct - http://prntscr.com/2gdnhq BUT in 320x480 showing same style - http://prntscr.com/2gdnsj

Comment: And so 'vh' does. I mean take a blank HTML page. put html like: "<div>watch me!</div>" and css: "div{width:30vh; background:#F00; margin-top:70vh; text-align:center; line-height:30vh}" and resize the window then to check the effect. I mean you can set 20% of the viewport height as 20vh;

Comment: I tried the vh but still it was not working on existing mobile queries code.